# Need to improve resolution of screenshot from OpenGL

Tags: opengl, printing, screenshot, resolution, opentk

I want to get a screen shot from current scene in OpenTK with good resolution. I am using GL.ReadPixels to get a photo for the scene.If I save the photo to disk; I found it with low resolution/quality.

following C# code is used to get a photo for the scene :

Bitmap bmp = null;

```
    if (GraphicsContext.CurrentContext != null)
    {
        glControl_window.Invalidate();
        int w = glControl_window.ClientSize.Width;
        int h = glControl_window.ClientSize.Height;
        bmp = new Bitmap(w, h);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data =
        bmp.LockBits(glControl_window.ClientRectangle, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);


        GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr, 
        PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

    }
```

when Initialize OpenTK use :

```
         this.glControl_window = new OpenTK.GLControl(new 
         OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode(new OpenTK.Graphics.ColorFormat(32), 
         24,8,4,new OpenTK.Graphics.ColorFormat(0),2,false));
```

with resize event of OpenTK I use :

```
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
```

with paint event of OpenTK I use (to enable zoom in/out by mouse) :

```
              float aspectRatio;
            if (Height == 0 || Width == 0) aspectRatio = 1f; else 
               aspectRatio = Width / (float)Height;

            double W = 20 * aspectRatio / CameraZoomScale, H = 20 / 
               CameraZoomScale;
            GL.Ortho(-0.5 * W, 0.5 * W, -0.5 * H, 0.5 * H, -600.0f, 600.0f);
```

I need to :

1.increase the resolution of the token screen shot during GL.ReadPixels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resolution screen shot of OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867008/resolution-screen-shot-of-opengl)

Comment: the other question was put on Hold!

Comment: @AhmedShaban If you go back and read why it was put on hold you will realize that it's questionable if you read and understood the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guidelines. In this specific case, you are better of posting two questions. One regarding how to increase the number of pixels read using GLReadPixels, and another one on how to upscale and print an Image from disk. I would be surprised if neither of these questions have been answered already.

Comment: Ok. thanks. in old post; i did't find the reason of hole. I modified this question be remove question about print scale.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that you are asking for two very different things here.

## Part 1 - render more pixels

The number of pixels to be read from a frame buffer using `GL.readpixels()` is always going to be the number of pixels corresponding to the buffer size. i.e. 1280x720 or something like that.

The only way to be able to read more pixels would be to **increase the size/resolution** of the OpenGL frame buffer.

Look for the part of your OpenTK code that initializes the open gl window and increase the resolution of the window. Look for something like:

```
public MainWindow()
    : base(
           1280, // initial width
           720,  // initial height
           ...
    )
{
    // your code
}
```

and change the resolution as desired. You might also have to override the `OnResize` method in your `GameWindow` class as described here: [How to change the viewport resolution in OpenTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858713/how-to-change-the-viewport-resolution-in-opentk?answertab=votes#tab-top)

## Part 2 - scaling an image

Once the bitmap has been saved to disk, any attempts to "increase" the resolution will involve upscaling the already existing image. This will ultimately result in a larger number of pixels, but also introduce **upscaling artifacts** depending on the image and which upscaling algoritm that is used. You can read more on different image scaling algoritms on wikipedia: [Image scaling Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms)

Comment: thanks for your help. I edit my question to show parts that I used with resize/paint event. Which part shall I modify.

Comment: I cannot say since it's unclear how you are running your app. Are you running it fullscreen, in a window? How big is your window when you you trigger the GL.readpixels() call? Do you understand the relationship between windowsize and buffersize?

Comment: it is a window with a size set by the user. I need to improve resolution.