# openGL gl.glReadPixels -- at higher resolution than screen size

Tags: opengl, blender

I'm trying to get the contents of a window, drawn in openGL, into a screenshot.

That window is at a set size (say 700 by 420), but I want to capture a screenshot of that window with an increased resolution of 1920 / 1080.

The full question is here, for blender:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128174/python-get-image-of-3d-view-for-streaming-realtime-eevee-rendering

under Edit #4, but this is essentially an openGL question:

Is it possible to get a higher resolution openGL screen of a window, without actually changing that window's resolution? (Similar to [untity's screen recorder](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/instant-screenshot-24122))?

A similar question was posted here: [Need to improve resolution of screenshot from OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910682/need-to-improve-resolution-of-screenshot-from-opengl), but the only answer says that changing the window resolution is the only solution.

I'm essentially trying to capture the 3D view in blender at a higher resolution than the current window size, but this same case can be applied to any window drawn with openGL that should be captured

Comment: "*this same case can be applied to any window drawn with openGL that should be captured*" But it's not. If you're using Blender, then you have to live within whatever restrictions Blender imposes upon you. If you're using "any window drawn with openGL", then you have full control, not only over OpenGL, but over that window too.

Comment: It is impossible to read back a higher resolution image from a window without re-rendering with the higher resolution in first place. You can do that without adjusting the window's size by rendering to a off-screen rendertarget (FBO) and read that back. Other than that, the only option is to resize the window.

Comment: @BDL Ok, do you know how this can be done using blenders GPU offscreen rendering? https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/gpu.html?highlight=gpu#module-gpu https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128174/python-get-image-of-3d-view-for-streaming-realtime-eevee-rendering